# I need to export complete stack in text file using wpaexporter (Windows Performance Toolkit), but just able to see the root elements

Tags: windows, window, wpa, xperf

How to export complete stack in text file using wpaexporter (Windows Performance Toolkit),I am just able to see the root elements only.